# Java Swing setVisible() Method not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make my program open up a new window when the "sign up" button is pressed by hiding the initial panel using `setVisible(false)` and then opening the new panel by using `setVisible(true)`. However, the program is only able to hide the initial panel, but the new panel doesn't show up. Why is that?

My hypothesis is that when I do    `add(this.loadInScreen)` and `add(this.signUpScreen)` it doesn't add the panels to the frame properly because when I used the debugger, the size of the frame's component array was only 1.

```
public class TypingGame extends JFrame {
private int width = 500;
private int height = 500;
private int borderThickness = 10;

private LoadInScreenPanel loadInScreen;
private SignUpScreenPanel signUpScreen;

// constructs main window
// EFFECTS: sets up window in which Typing Game will be played and sign up/ login page will be
public TypingGame() {
    super("Typing Game");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(width, height);
    setResizable(false);
    Border border = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, borderThickness));
    this.getRootPane().setBorder(border);

    loadInScreen = new LoadInScreenPanel();
    signUpScreen = new SignUpScreenPanel();
    add(this.loadInScreen);
    add(this.signUpScreen);
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JTextField textField = (JTextField) this.getComponent(2);
    JLabel successMessage = (JLabel) this.getComponent(5);
    String username = textField.getText();
    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if (action.equals("login")) {
        Boolean success = login.signIn(username);
        if (success) {
            successMessage.setText("Login successful!");
            game.getContentPane().removeAll();
            gamePanel = new TypingGamePanel();
            game.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
            game.revalidate();
        } else {
            successMessage.setText("Login failed, try again!");
            System.out.println("bye");
        }
    } else if (action.equals("sign up")) {
        game.getLoadInScreen().setVisible(false);
        game.getSignUpScreen().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop using `getComponent` - it's dangerous and severely limits the extendability of the class and is making assumptions about how the container is implemented.  Make use instance fields instead.  You should also take a look at [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Wow, that was easy to implement! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Stop using `getComponent`, it's a dangerous, makes assumptions, is difficult to read, is impossible to scale, maintain and manage.  Instead, make use of property accessors (ie "getters") backed by instance fields.

For a "simpler" workflow, make use of [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Having said that, you're probably also benefit from having a read through:

- [Model-View-Controller](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-design-pattern/)
- [Observer Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)
- [Dependency Injection in Java](https://medium.com/groupon-eng/dependency-injection-in-java-9e9438aa55ae)

You should also decouple your code into "areas of responsibility", so any one class is focused on doing just one job.

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DefaultUserAuthenticationService authenticationService = new DefaultUserAuthenticationService();
                UserRegistrationService registrationService = new DefaultUserRegistrationService(authenticationService);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane(registrationService, authenticationService));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface User {
        public String getUserName();
    }

    public interface UserRegistrationService {
        public interface Observer {
            public void registrationWasSuccessful(UserRegistrationService source);

            public void registrationDidFail(UserRegistrationService source);
        }

        public void registerUser(String userName, char[] password, Observer observer);
    }

    public interface UserAuthenticationService {
        public interface Observer {
            public void authenticationWasSuccessful(UserAuthenticationService source, User user);

            public void authenticationDidFail(UserAuthenticationService source);
        }

        public void authenticateUser(String userName, char[] password, Observer observer);

        public void logout(User user);
    }

    public class DefaultUserRegistrationService implements UserRegistrationService {
        private DefaultUserAuthenticationService authenticationService;

        public DefaultUserRegistrationService(DefaultUserAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
            this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerUser(String userName, char[] password, Observer observer) {
            // Simulate some kind of service
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                    if (userName == null || password == null || userName.isBlank() || password.length == 0) {
                        observer.registrationDidFail(DefaultUserRegistrationService.this);
                    } else {
                        if (authenticationService.addUser(userName, password)) {
                            observer.registrationWasSuccessful(DefaultUserRegistrationService.this);
                        } else {
                            observer.registrationDidFail(DefaultUserRegistrationService.this);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public class DefaultUserAuthenticationService implements UserAuthenticationService {

        protected class DefaultUser implements User {

            private String userName;
            private char[] password;

            public DefaultUser(String userName, char[] password) {
                this.userName = userName;
                this.password = password;
            }

            @Override
            public String getUserName() {
                return userName;
            }

            public char[] getPassword() {
                return password;
            }
        }

        private List<DefaultUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

        protected boolean addUser(String userName, char[] password) {
            for (User user : users) {
                if (user.getUserName().equals(userName)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            users.add(new DefaultUser(userName, password));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticateUser(String userName, char[] password, Observer observer) {
            // Simulate some service
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                    for (DefaultUser user : users) {
                        if (user.getUserName().equals(userName) && Arrays.equals(password, user.getPassword())) {
                            observer.authenticationWasSuccessful(DefaultUserAuthenticationService.this, user);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    observer.authenticationDidFail(DefaultUserAuthenticationService.this);
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void logout(User user) {
            // Remove active user as required
        }

    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        public enum View {
            LAUNCH, LOGIN, REGISTRATION, GAME;
        }

        private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

        private LaunchPane launchPane;
        private RegistrationPane registrationPane;
        private LoginPane loginPane;
        private GamePane gamePane;

        private UserRegistrationService registrationService;
        private UserAuthenticationService authenticationService;

        public MainPane(UserRegistrationService registrationService, UserAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
            this.registrationService = registrationService;
            this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            add(getLaunchPane(), View.LAUNCH);
            add(getRegistrationPane(), View.REGISTRATION);
            add(getLoginPane(), View.LOGIN);
            add(getGamePane(), View.GAME);

            navigateToLauncher();
        }

        protected void add(JComponent component, View view) {
            add(component, view.name());
        }

        protected void navigateTo(View view) {
            cardLayout.show(this, view.name());
        }

        protected void navigateToRegistration() {
            getRegistrationPane().willPresentView();
            navigateTo(View.REGISTRATION);
        }

        protected void navigateToLogin() {
            getLoginPane().willPresentView();
            navigateTo(View.LOGIN);
        }

        protected void navigateToGame(User user) {
            getGamePane().setUser(user);
            navigateTo(View.GAME);
        }

        protected void navigateToLauncher() {
            navigateTo(View.LAUNCH);
        }

        public UserRegistrationService getRegistrationService() {
            return registrationService;
        }

        public UserAuthenticationService getAuthenticationService() {
            return authenticationService;
        }

        protected LaunchPane getLaunchPane() {
            if (launchPane != null) {
                return launchPane;
            }
            launchPane = new LaunchPane(new LaunchPane.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void doesRequireRegisteration(LaunchPane source) {
                    navigateToRegistration();
                }

                @Override
                public void doesRequireLogin(LaunchPane source) {
                    navigateToLogin();
                }
            });
            return launchPane;
        }

        protected RegistrationPane getRegistrationPane() {
            if (registrationPane != null) {
                return registrationPane;
            }

            registrationPane = new RegistrationPane(getRegistrationService(), new RegistrationPane.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void registrationWasSuccessful(RegistrationPane source) {
                    navigateToLauncher();
                }

                @Override
                public void didCancelRegistration(RegistrationPane source) {
                    navigateToLauncher();
                }
            });
            return registrationPane;
        }

        protected LoginPane getLoginPane() {
            if (loginPane != null) {
                return loginPane;
            }

            loginPane = new LoginPane(getAuthenticationService(), new LoginPane.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void loginWasSuccessful(LoginPane source, User user) {
                    navigateToGame(user);
                }

                @Override
                public void didCancelLogin(LoginPane source) {
                    navigateToLauncher();
                }
            });
            return loginPane;
        }

        protected GamePane getGamePane() {
            if (gamePane != null) {
                return gamePane;
            }

            gamePane = new GamePane(getAuthenticationService(), new GamePane.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void didLogout(GamePane source) {
                    navigateToLauncher();
                }
            });

            return gamePane;
        }

    }

    public class LaunchPane extends JPanel {
        public interface Observer {
            public void doesRequireRegisteration(LaunchPane source);
            public void doesRequireLogin(LaunchPane source);
        }

        public LaunchPane(Observer observer) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton signUpButton = new JButton("Sign up");
            JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login in");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);

            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Welcome");
            titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            titleLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 32, 0));
            titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

            add(titleLabel, gbc);
            add(signUpButton, gbc);
            add(loginButton, gbc);

            signUpButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    observer.doesRequireRegisteration(LaunchPane.this);
                }
            });
            loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    observer.doesRequireLogin(LaunchPane.this);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class RegistrationPane extends JPanel {
        public interface Observer {
            public void registrationWasSuccessful(RegistrationPane source);
            public void didCancelRegistration(RegistrationPane source);
        }

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;

        private JButton registerButton;
        private JButton cancelButton;

        private JPanel actionPane;

        private Observer observer;
        private UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

        public RegistrationPane(UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService, Observer observer) {
            this.userRegistrationService = userRegistrationService;
            this.observer = observer;
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);

            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Register");
            titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            titleLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 32, 0));
            titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

            add(titleLabel, gbc);
            add(getContentPane(), gbc);
            add(new JSeparator(), gbc);
            add(getActionPane(), gbc);
        }

        public UserRegistrationService getUserRegistrationService() {
            return userRegistrationService;
        }

        public Observer getObserver() {
            return observer;
        }

        public void willPresentView() {
            setEnabled(true);
            userNameField.setText(null);
            passwordField.setText(null);
        }

        protected String getUserName() {
            return userNameField.getText();
        }

        protected char[] getPassword() {
            return passwordField.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            super.setEnabled(enabled);
            userNameField.setEnabled(enabled);
            passwordField.setEnabled(enabled);
            registerButton.setEnabled(enabled);
            cancelButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }

        protected JPanel getContentPane() {
            if (contentPane != null) {
                return contentPane;
            }

            contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);

            contentPane.add(new JLabel("User name: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            contentPane.add(new JLabel("Password: "), gbc);

            userNameField = new JTextField(10);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            contentPane.add(userNameField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            contentPane.add(passwordField, gbc);

            return contentPane;
        }

        protected JPanel getActionPane() {
            if (actionPane != null) {
                return actionPane;
            }

            registerButton = new JButton("Register");
            cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

            registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setEnabled(false);
                    getUserRegistrationService().registerUser(getUserName(), getPassword(), new UserRegistrationService.Observer() {
                        @Override
                        public void registrationWasSuccessful(UserRegistrationService source) {
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    setEnabled(true);
                                    getObserver().registrationWasSuccessful(RegistrationPane.this);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void registrationDidFail(UserRegistrationService source) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RegistrationPane.this, "Registration did fail", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getObserver().didCancelRegistration(RegistrationPane.this);
                }
            });

            actionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            actionPane.add(registerButton);
            actionPane.add(cancelButton);

            return actionPane;
        }
    }

    public class LoginPane extends JPanel {
        public interface Observer {
            public void loginWasSuccessful(LoginPane source, User user);
            public void didCancelLogin(LoginPane source);
        }

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;
        private JButton registerButton;
        private JButton cancelButton;

        private JPanel actionPane;

        private Observer observer;
        private UserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationService;

        public LoginPane(UserAuthenticationService userRegistrationService, Observer observer) {
            this.userAuthenticationService = userRegistrationService;
            this.observer = observer;
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);

            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Authenticate");
            titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            titleLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 32, 0));
            titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

            add(titleLabel, gbc);
            add(getContentPane(), gbc);
            add(new JSeparator(), gbc);
            add(getActionPane(), gbc);
        }

        public UserAuthenticationService getUserAuthenticationService() {
            return userAuthenticationService;
        }

        public Observer getObserver() {
            return observer;
        }

        public void willPresentView() {
            userNameField.setText(null);
            passwordField.setText(null);
            setEnabled(true);
        }

        protected String getUserName() {
            return userNameField.getText();
        }

        protected char[] getPassword() {
            return passwordField.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            super.setEnabled(enabled);
            userNameField.setEnabled(enabled);
            passwordField.setEnabled(enabled);
            registerButton.setEnabled(enabled);
            cancelButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }

        protected JPanel getContentPane() {
            if (contentPane != null) {
                return contentPane;
            }

            contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);

            contentPane.add(new JLabel("User name: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            contentPane.add(new JLabel("Password: "), gbc);

            userNameField = new JTextField(10);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            contentPane.add(userNameField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            contentPane.add(passwordField, gbc);

            return contentPane;
        }

        protected JPanel getActionPane() {
            if (actionPane != null) {
                return actionPane;
            }

            registerButton = new JButton("Login");
            cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

            registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setEnabled(false);
                    getUserAuthenticationService().authenticateUser(getUserName(), getPassword(), new UserAuthenticationService.Observer() {
                        @Override
                        public void authenticationWasSuccessful(UserAuthenticationService source, User user) {
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    getObserver().loginWasSuccessful(LoginPane.this, user);
                                    setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void authenticationDidFail(UserAuthenticationService source) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPane.this, "Registration did fail", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getObserver().didCancelLogin(LoginPane.this);
                }
            });

            actionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            actionPane.add(registerButton);
            actionPane.add(cancelButton);

            return actionPane;
        }
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        public interface Observer {
            public void didLogout(GamePane source);
        }

        private JLabel userLabel;

        private User user;

        public GamePane(UserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationService, Observer observer) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton logoutButton = new JButton("Logout button");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);

            userLabel = new JLabel("nobody");
            userLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            userLabel.setFont(userLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Do you want to play a game?");
            titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

            JPanel titlePane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            titlePane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 32, 0));
            titlePane.add(userLabel, gbc);
            titlePane.add(titleLabel, gbc);

            add(titlePane, gbc);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(32, 32, 32, 32);
            add(logoutButton, gbc);

            logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    userAuthenticationService.logout(getUser());
                    setUser(null);
                    observer.didLogout(GamePane.this);
                }
            });
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
            userLabel.setText(user == null ? "Nobody" : user.getUserName());
        }

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

But wait a second, when a user successfully registers, they are taken back to the "launch" view, wouldn't it be better to have them go straight to the "login" view?

Now, because the navigation is generally controller by the `LaunchPane`, it's a simple thing to change, for example...

```
protected RegistrationPane getRegistrationPane() {
    if (registrationPane != null) {
        return registrationPane;
    }

    registrationPane = new RegistrationPane(getRegistrationService(), new RegistrationPane.Observer() {
        @Override
        public void registrationWasSuccessful(RegistrationPane source) {
            navigateToLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public void didCancelRegistration(RegistrationPane source) {
            navigateToLauncher();
        }
    });
    return registrationPane;
}
```

> But I want to get more information from the user during registration!

So?  You could make the `RegistrationPane` another type of navigation controller, allowing a user to navigate through a number of sub views, controlled by the `RegistrationPane`, till they reach the end.

The same thing goes the `GamePane`.  Because they are isolated classes, they can do what ever functionality they need to do, so long as they keep up the contracts they have with the `LaunchPane` (via their observers)